# how to add javascript function to a class of active?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, codeigniter

how to add javascript function to a class of active ??
I do not understand completely about javascript.

if i click menu its like remove and add new class nav active.

```html
  <div id="sidebar">        
    <ul id="mainNav">           
            <li id="navDashboard" class="nav active">
              <span class="icon-home"></span>
               <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/admin');?>">Beranda</a>              
            </li>

        <li id="navPages" class="nav">
        <span class="icon-document-alt-stroke"></span>
        <a href="javascript:;">Data Profil</a>              

        <ul class="subNav">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/lokasi');?>">Peta Lokasi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/siteplan');?>">Site Plan</a></li>
        </ul>

        </li>
```

Comment: Check if you have a class using jQuery `hasClass` and you can add a class using `addClass`..like,`if ($(this).hasClass('even')) {$(this).addClass('newclass');}`..Try it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass(your class)
         .addClass('active');
});
```

You have to define the selector you want to do something.